# Obtener una parte de un log powershell

Tags: powershell

tengo este script de powershell que l oque hace es consultar el registro de eventos (eventwvr), el comando que uso es

```
Get-EventLog Application -InstanceID 3221228551
```

Lo que devuelve

```
   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
    5128 dic 15 11:47  Error       Windows Search Se...   3221228551 No está...
```

Lo que quiero obtener es solamente el tiempo y guardarlo en una string o algo asi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo, necesitas algo así:

```
$logs = Get-EventLog Application -InstanceID 3221228551 
$TiempoLogs  = $logs | Select-Object -Property Time
```

un saludo.